# Database Schema Corrupts Unit Tests

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, h2

Because we are using two different databases for logging tables, we were forced to add a schema to the table annotation, e.g.

```
@Table(name = "TestLog", schema="OTHER_DB.dbo")
public class TestLog { ... }
```

This works just fine in the code itself, however, it causes many unit tests to fail, because an in-memory-db (H2) is used and cannot cope with the schema value in the annotation.

Is there a possibility to configure the annotation in a way that the schema value is not used in a test context?

Comment: You could use XML mapping

Comment: Why don't you simply create the schema? http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_schema

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for your suggestion. However, I end up with an error `[ERROR] Caused by org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement :  CREATE SCHEMA OTHER_DB.[*]DBO`. Also we use a mssql database regularly, so maybe it isn't even possible to use `OTHER_DB.DBO` (because it expects only one parameter without a `.`)?

Comment: An identifier can not contain a `.` you need to use: `create schema other_db`

Comment: The creation of the schema now works, however, since we use `OTHER_DB.dbo` as a schema in the entity, it expects that `dbo` is a table. Because the select statement used in the code is `SELECT [...] FROM other_db.dbo_Testlog`, which is not working with only `other_db` as a schema.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, do you happen to know a workaround to fix the issue with two identifiers in the schema. :) (I wasn't sure if you got a notification of my first message, sorry I didn't mean to bother you)

Comment: You apparently not only have different schema, but different catalogs as well. But I don't think h2 supports multiple catalogs in the same database.